# append html to an element with no named div

Tags: jquery

i do not have control over the html of this form, which also is not sitting in a properly named div. so from what i know about .append, i don't know how to target what i'm looking for.

after this line of code, i would like to insert a similar field

```
<input class="field" name="email" type="text">
```

something like

```
<input class="field" name="segment" value="website" type="hidden">
```

i imagine some sort of regular expression would work well for this?

Comment: Is your shift key broken?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("input[name=email]").parent().append('<input class="field" name="segment" value="website" type="hidden"/>');
```

That will target your email input, go up to that input's parent element in the DOM tree, then append your hidden field.

**EDIT:**

[Here is a pretty basic jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2qtjw02z/) of the example. *Note* for the example, I changed your appended input type to `text` to demonstrate the code working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)** for inserting next to an element

```js
$('[name="email"]').after($('<input/>', {
  class: 'field',
  name: 'segment',
  value: 'website',
  type: 'hidden'
}))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="field" name="email" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I was not sure from your question what you really wanted, I covered 3 possible cases:

```js
var input2Append = $('input.field[name=email]');

//this places another input after the email input
$('#add').click(function() {
  input2Append.after('<input class="field" name="segment" value="website">');
});
//this changes the properties of the email input
$('#change').click(function() {
  input2Append.prop({'name':'segment','value':'website'});
});
//this shows/hides the inputs
$('#hide').click(function(){
  $('input').toggle()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="field" name="email" type="text"><br><button id="add">Add input</button><button id="change">Change input</button><button id="hide">Hide/show inputs</button>
```

[Append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) adds one element inside another element (good for containing elements). Since you cannot place HTML inside an `input` element like you'd do in a `div` (i.e. inner content), you don't see any result when you use `append`.

Therefore if you want to add other inputs after the one you're selecting, you should use [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) instead.